# Severe Issue with New Orders & Adding Items/Shipping

Tags: magento2, orders, shipping, tax, development

Currently attempting to sort an ongoing issue with opening new orders.

When trying to obtain either shipping methods or add a new item on a new order, Magento throws the following error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/tax.phtml on line 13
#0 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/tax.phtml(13): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/var/www/vhosts...', 13, Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals\Tax), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Totals.php(161): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Totals.php(178): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals->renderTotal(Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total), NULL, 1)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals.phtml(15): Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals->renderTotals()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Totals), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#11 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('totals')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('totals')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('totals')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('totals', true)
#19 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('totals', true)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/data.phtml(83): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('totals')
#21 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#22 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Data), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#23 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('data')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('data')
#29 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('data')
#30 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('data', true)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('data', true)
#32 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/form.phtml(23): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('data')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#34 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Form), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#35 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#36 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#37 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#38 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#39 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('order_create_fo...')
#40 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('order_create_fo...')
#41 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('order_create_fo...')
#42 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('order_create_fo...', true)
#43 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('order_create_fo...', true)
#44 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php(173): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form')
#45 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/form/container.phtml(15): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Container->getFormHtml()
#46 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#47 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create), '/var/www/vhosts...', Array)
#48 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/var/www/vhosts...')
#49 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Template.php(104): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#50 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#51 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#52 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('order_content')
#53 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('order_content')
#54 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('order_content')
#55 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('order_content', true)
#56 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('order_content')
#57 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('content')
#58 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#59 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('content')
#60 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('content', true)
#61 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('content')
#62 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('main.col')
#63 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#64 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('main.col')
#65 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('main.col', true)
#66 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('main.col')
#67 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('admin.scope.col...')
#68 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#69 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('admin.scope.col...')
#70 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('admin.scope.col...', true)
#71 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('admin.scope.col...')
#72 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...')
#73 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#74 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#75 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', true)
#76 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...')
#77 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content')
#78 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#79 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#80 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', true)
#81 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content')
#82 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
#83 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#84 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#85 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
#86 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
#87 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page')
#88 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#89 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#90 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', true)
#91 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page')
#92 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
#93 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#94 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#95 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#96 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#97 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(492): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#98 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(241): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#99 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(162): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#100 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#101 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(119): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#102 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#103 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#104 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('launch', Array, Array)
#105 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#106 /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#107 {main}
```

No idea where to even begin solving this, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are running Magento in developer mode. This is a warning and not a fatal error. Error reporting level should be set to only severe on a production environment.

Having said this, examine what occurs in file:
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/totals/tax.phtml line 13.

The code expects an array to be passed to the foreach but something else is being passed.

Comment: Already had a look, however I'm not remotely familiar enough with how Magento passes data to the file in question to diagnose the problem. 

`<?php global $taxIter; $taxIter++; ?>
<?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Tax\Helper\Data')->displayFullSummary()): ?>
<?php $isTop = 1; ?>
            <?php foreach ($block->getTotal()->getFullInfo() as $info): ?>`

Seems to be something to do with a helper however.